# How do I use --node-arg in npx / npm version 7?

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

`npx` used to have a [`--node-arg` option](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-exec) to specify options for node. In npm v7, this results in:

```
npx: the --n argument has been removed.
See `npm help exec` for more information
```

Which states:

```
The --node-arg and -n options are removed.
```

Without any information being supplied about their replacement. This is not helpful.

I have tried using `--`. For example to run `npx jest -t 'API work'` with a node option of `-r`:

```
npx -r dotenv/config dotenv_config_path=/home/mike/Code/myapp/.env.local -- jest -t 'API works'
```

However this doesn't do anything.

Comment: See comment at the bottom of the page [here](https://github.com/npm/npx/issues/5) - it suggests using `--node-options` instead.

Answer (score 15):

I just wanted to shout out [RobC's Answer in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66459448/how-do-i-use-node-arg-in-npx-npm-version-7#comment117492581_66459448), as it did work for me. `--node-arg` has been replaced by `--node-options`. For example, with Fastify and Typescript:

```js
// package.json
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "dev": "npx --node-options='-r dotenv/config' tsnd --respawn src/index.ts",
    ...
  },
```

Make sure to wrap all of your commands together in **single quotes** (`''`) if you're using it in a `package.json`!

Comment: With node 14, it's `--node-arg` (singular)

Comment: You're correct, fixed it.

Comment: @colinux rescued me twice, first with node arg, then on the second check of answer with plural...

Comment: I'm using node 18 and the correct option is `--node-options` and not `--node-arg`

Comment: With NodeJS 20 (npm v10), even the `--node-options` didn't work for me. Instead I used `NODE_OPTIONS="..." npx command` variation to pass the args.