# Using max-old-space-size in NPX

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, package.json, npx

I was updating the scripts in package.json which uses the "./node_modules" to use NPX commands and came across ng build with "max-old-space-size" argument. I have converted the command as following from

```
node --max-old-space-size=10240 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod
```

to

```
npx --max-old-space-size=10240 ng build --prod
```

I have two questions:

- The npx command runs without errors, but couldn't verify if it's using the max-old-space-size argument. So, am I doing it right?
- Is there any better way to reduce the repeated "./node_modules" in scripts?

Answer (score 1):

It won't work, you should include node parameters in --node-options.

```bash
npx --node-options='--max-old-space-size=10240' ng build --prod
```

Related:
[How do I use --node-arg in npx / npm version 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66459448/how-do-i-use-node-arg-in-npx-npm-version-7)